# React State not working as expected, is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get my head around some react state work, specifically working with arrays in a state item.

In my test I have a group of items, each item has an id and a button to star those items. If the item is starred then the id will be removed from the state array.

This is the code I have but for some reason it's very sporadic as to when it works.

```
  const [starred, setStarred] = useState(null);
  const [starredArray, setStarredArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (starred !== null) {
      if (starredArray.includes(starred)) {
        const newArray = starredArray;
        const index = newArray.indexOf(starred);
        if (index > -1) {
          newArray.splice(index, 1);
          setStarredArray(newArray);
        }
      } else {
        setStarredArray([...starredArray, starred]);
      }
      setStarred(null); // reset for next
    }
  }, [starred, setStarred]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("starredArray");
    console.log(starredArray);
  }, [starredArray, setStarredArray]);
```

And then I have a button element to trigger each stars action which looks like this on many elements

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.previewStar}
    onPress={() => setStarred(previewId)}
  >
    <Icon name="star" size={20} color="dodgerblue" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Am I going in completely the wrong direction here with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const newArray = starredArray;`

You are mutating the original array with this, see the following:

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
const b = a;

b.splice(1,1);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Given you have what I'm guessing are just primitives as they are Ids, you should do:

`const newArray = [...starredArray];`

Before you do your removal, e.g:

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
const b = [...a];

b.splice(1,1);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Alternately, you could:

`setStarredArray(starredArray.filter(item => starred !== item));`